# DOMのsetAttribute()メソッドに属性を2つ加えたい!

Tags: php, xml, dom

現在、PHPで以下のXMLファイルの作成をしようと考えており、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <MarkerData>
    <marker lat="35.507456" lng="139.61758499999996">
      <icon>atlas</icon>
      < content ><![CDATA[
        <p>新横浜駅</p>
      ]]></content>
    </marker>
  </MarkerData>
</root>
```

以下のようなプログラムを作ったのはいいものの、setAttribute()メソッドの部分に2つの属性を入れる方法がわからず困っています。

もし何かご存知の方は是非ご教授ください!! 
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
// インスタンスの生成
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// prefs ノードを追加
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('root'));
$MarkerData = $root->appendChild($dom->createElement('MarkerData'));
$marker = $MarkerData->appendChild($dom->createElement('marker'));


// code 属性の追加
$marker->setAttribute('ここがわかりません。');
// 要素ノードを追加してテキストを入れる
$marker->appendChild($dom->createElement('icon', 'atlas'));
$marker->appendChild($dom->createElement('content', '<![CDATA[
        <p>新横浜駅</p>
      ]]>'));

//XML を整形（改行・字下げ）して出力
$dom->formatOutput = true;
//保存（上書き）
$dom->save('prefs.xml');
```

Comment: [DOMElement::setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/ja/domelement.setattribute.php) 複数のアトリビュートを一度に設定するＡＰＩにはなってないですから、別々に設定する必要があると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute()` を二回呼べばいいのではないでしょうか。

```
$marker->setAttribute('lat', '35.507456');
$marker->setAttribute('lng', '139.61758499999996');
```

なおマニュアルのコメントにサンプルコードが書かれていましたから、こちらも参考になるかと思います。

[PHP: DOMDocument - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/class.domdocument.php#82447)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！

そのやり方で上手くいきました!!